# Sqlite: convert semicolon separated positive values to negative values

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, multiplication

I have a SQLite table that look like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| Julia | 43 |
| Julia | 12;54 |
| Julia | 10;7;32 |
| Julia | *NULL* |
| Julia | 11;42 |

So my aim is to multiply all values in the column `value` by `-1`. When I run something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET value = value * -1
WHERE name = 'Julia' 
  AND value IS NOT NULL;
```

this leads to this table:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| Julia | -43 |
| Julia | -12 |
| Julia | -10 |
| Julia | *NULL* |
| Julia | -11 |

The second and third  semicolon separated values are lost. But the output table should look like this one:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| Julia | -43 |
| Julia | -12;-54 |
| Julia | -10;-7;-32 |
| Julia | *NULL* |
| Julia | -11;-42 |

Comment: Now would be a good time to fix your database design and stop storing CSV values like this.  Really, the only time storing CSV is justifiable is if you _don't_ have requirements such as yours, to manipulate/access the individual points of CSV data.  Consider getting each CSV value onto a separate row.

Comment: I know, but I have no authorisation to modify the structure of the table.

Comment: Are all the values in the table positive?

Comment: Yes they are all positiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can replace all occurrences  of `';'` with `';-'` and concatenate a `'-'` at the beginning of `value`:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET value = '-' || REPLACE(value, ';', ';-')
WHERE name = 'Julia' AND value IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=56fe7bd0fe8e0c4e8467c40ad8326ad6).